# Failed to lift app: Error: Sails is taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Sails has a default timeout by default when starting the app. How to remove this or maybe how to extend the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  confing/env I set hookTimeout in development.js and production.js currently hookTimeout 80000 to 320000.It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).